# Nested ng-options in ng-repeat - How to get selected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have a ng-repeat that lists parts of the day for schedules to go into. For each line, I need to show the available playlists.

The issue that I'm having is how to match the two up so that we show the currently selected item in the drop down.

```
<div ng-repeat="daypart in dayparts track by $index" class="content_dayparts">
    <div class="info_col_1">{{daypart.name}}</div>
    <div class="info_col_2">
<select ng-model="daypart.assignment" 
ng-options="p.id as p.name for p in playlists" 
ng-change="assignPlaylist($index, daypart.id)">
</select></div>
```

When the "dayparts" change, the following function fires:

```
$scope.checkPlaylistAssignment = function () {
    // So... We need to loop over all playlists, get their daypartId and store what it matches.
    angular.forEach($scope.playlists, function(v,i) {
        angular.forEach($scope.dayparts, function (vb, ib) {
            if ($scope.playlists[i].daypartId == $scope.dayparts[ib].id) {
                console.log("We have a match: "+$scope.playlists[i].daypartId+" Daypart Id is: "+$scope.dayparts[ib].id);
                $scope.dayparts[ib].assignment = $scope.playlists[i];
            } else {
                console.log("Assigned Playlist is: "+$scope.playlists[i].daypartId+" Daypart Id is: "+$scope.dayparts[ib].id);
            }
        });
    });
    console.log($scope.dayparts);
}
```

"daypart.assignment" is set to the playlist object, but still, the assigned playlist does not show in the select. What am I missing here?

Here is a screenshot of the dev console showing that the assignment IS set.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the dev console showing that the assignment IS set.]

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a fiddle if anyone wants to play around with this: http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/95jufwz9/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not the most efficient code, the code you have above for `checkPlaylistAssignment` should work based on solely what you have provided in this question.

I checked the jsfiddle that you sent and I created the following `checkPlaylistAssignment` which will assign the right assignment object to each daypart object when it is run.

What I'm doing is first I index the playlists by their id and then I go through each daypart and assign the right playlist object.  I first created an index so that you avoid having to loop through your playlist for each single dayparts object.

```
$scope.checkPlaylistAssignment = function () {
    var playlistIndexedById = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.playlists, function (playlist){
        playlistIndexedById[playlist.id] = playlist;
    });
    angular.forEach($scope.dayparts, function(daypart) {
        var curr = daypart.assignment;
        daypart.assignment = playlistIndexedById[curr.id];
    });
    console.log('playlistIndexedById',playlistIndexedById);
};
$scope.checkPlaylistAssignment();
```

I also created an updated fiddle that shows you that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/95jufwz9/12/

Comment: That only works if the playlists are 1, 2, 3... Change the ID's so they're not sequential, and it breaks again. 

http://jsfiddle.net/95jufwz9/13/

This is an odd one. The only solution I've found so far is to use another array to track the assignments, but that's cluttered on the back end. The assignment is part of dayparts, and logically, I'd like it to stay that way.

I appreciate the answer.

Comment: @JasonMaggard, no, it doesn't matter what order it is in, it will still work.  The problem in your link is that there were no playlist entries for id 1 or 3, you changed the keys to 15 and 38 for those entries.  Here is a jsfiddle were the ids are not sequential, but I made sure that the ids were still in the list: http://jsfiddle.net/95jufwz9/14/